# How to perform POST operation on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, windows-phone-8.1

I am struggling to successfully implement a `POST` operation within `Windows Phone 8.1`.

`PostMessage` method executes without any exceptions being caught.
However, the `POST` method within `MessagesController` never gets invoked.

How do I perform a `POST` for `Windows Phone 8.1`?

The code is below:

```
internal async Task PostMessage(string text)
{
    Globals.MemberId = 1;
    int memberId = 2;

    // server to POST to
    string url = @"http://localhost:17634/api/messages";

    try
    {
        // HTTP web request
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        // Write the request Asynchronously 
        using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,
                                                                 httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
        {
                //create some json string
            var message = new Message() { FromId = Globals.MemberId, ToId = memberId, Content = text, Timestamp = DateTime.Now };
            var json = string.Format("{0}{1}", "action=", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));

            // convert json to byte array
            byte[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            // Write the bytes to the stream
            await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}


public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Message message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public int FromId { get; set; }
    public int ToId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) resolved my issue.
The updated client is as follows:

```
        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            // New code:
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Globals.URL_PREFIX);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var message = new Message() { MessageId = 0, FromId = Globals.MemberId, ToId = memberId, Content = text, Timestamp = DateTime.Now };
            var json_object = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("api/messages", new StringContent(json_object.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            Debug.Assert(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. The function accepts an `payload` of type `T`. The server accepts a JSON object and returns a JSON response.

```
public async static Task SendRequestPacket<T>(object payload)
        {
            Uri theUri = new Uri("the_uri");
            //Create an Http client and set the headers we want 
            HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient();
            aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = theUri.Host;

            //Create a Json Serializer for our type 
            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

            // use the serializer to write the object to a MemoryStream 
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            jsonSer.WriteObject(ms, payload);
            ms.Position = 0;

            //use a Stream reader to construct the StringContent (Json) 

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            StringContent theContent = new StringContent(sr.ReadToEnd(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //Post the data 
            HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, theContent);

            if (aResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await aResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
            }
            else
            {
                // show the response status code 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just dont use `HttpWebRequest` if you are not forced to in any way.
This example is using `HttpClient()` and it is good to always have the client created once and not every time you make a request.

So in your class add:

```
private static HttpClient _client;

public static Uri ServerBaseUri
{
    get { return new Uri("http://localhost:17634/api"); }
}

public ClassConstructor()
{
_client = new HttpClient();
}

internal async Task<ResponseType> PostMessage(string text)
{
    Globals.MemberId = 1;
    int memberId = 2;

    try
    {
        var js = "{  JSON_OBJECT }";

        var json = new StringContent(js);
        json.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        var response = await Client.PostAsync(new Uri(ServerBaseUri, "/messages"), json);

        var reply = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    } catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

More on [HttpClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx).

Comment: I do not see where object "reader" is declared in your example. With that line commented out, I attempted to execute the code. However, I still have not observed the Post method to get executed in my controller.

Comment: The response object reflects the following status: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1,

Comment: I have changed that to `ReadAsStringAsync` so you can see the response. Please check the answer again.

Comment: The error code you are receiving is coming from your server. Try to debug the request with fiddler to see the packages. Also are you sure that your server is responding ? If so check a header of a successful request and compare to your header (the one you get through fiddler) to see what's wrong.

Comment: I get a new error with your updated snippet: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Message' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)

Comment: U are using multipart data.. please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900934/httpclient-uploading-multipartformdata-to-play-2-framework. I had similar problems. I could help you more if the API was online.

Comment: I added that snippet from the provided link and it is still not working. Is a POST really this complicated using the WebApi framework?

Comment: It really shouldn't :) Please check the updated answer once again. This one is as simple as possible and it should work. If you are trying to send multiparty form data the you need to consider the answer I have on the link that I wrote before. Depending on your webservice there could be many reasons why this fails. The only way to debug this is to compare the header files as mentioned before. U can do this with fiddler.

Comment: I'm oblivious to the HTTP as a protocol (i.e. headers). As a result, I'm not sure even how to use the information that Fidler provides. I will review your updated answer. By-the-way, does my MessagesController and Message class look okay?

Comment: I don't see the use of MessagesController class anywhere. Also regarding Message class you could use it to parse the reply instead of using  `ReadAsStringAsync`

Comment: I've also used the Windows Phone 8.1 sample project to view their WebRequest code. When I plug in my url into their app it also fails to perform a put operation. What's weird is the Get operation works flawless. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-81-samples-08631ca7

Comment: Scroll down to the end of the first code snippet of my post to view the other classes involved.

Comment: Yes. It's completed. See my answer below. Thanks.